# Django filebrowser exception. I can't understand what's wrong

Tags: python, django, django-filebrowser

I'm trying make it work. And I have a lot of errors, but this one is most weird. Help me understand what's wrong here, please.
Here is log:

```
KeyError at /
'filebrowser'
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    'filebrowser'
Exception Location: /home/vhosts/malinnikov.tomsk.ru/private/new_malinnikov/filebrowser/sites.py in get_default_site, line 88
Python Executable:  /opt/python27/django/1.4/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.0
```

Error during template rendering:
In template /home/vhosts/malinnikov.tomsk.ru/httpdocs/templates/index.html, error at line 69

```
59  {% endblock %}
60  
61  {% block content %}
62      {% if cover_photos %}
63          <div id="cover-photos">
64          {% for object in cover_photos %}
65              <div class="cover-photo {% if forloop.last %}cover-photo-last {% endif %}">
66                  {% if object.link %}
67                      <a href="{{ object.link }}">{% else %}
68                      <a href="{% url gallery_index_page %}">{% endif %}<img
69                      src="{% version object.photo.path 'big' %}"
70                      {% if object.photo_in_gallery.title %}
71                          title="{{ object.photo_in_gallery.title }}"
72                          alt="Фотография {{ object.photo_in_gallery.title }}"
73                      {% endif %}
74                      /></a>
75                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
76                      <div class="delete-link">
77                          <a
78                              title="Удалить фото"
79                              target="_blank"
```

It's code of function from filebrowser/sites.py where exception is located.

```
78. def get_default_site(app_name='filebrowser'):
79. """
80. Returns the default site. This function uses Django's url resolution method to
81    obtain the name of the default site.
82.  """
83. # Get the name of the default site:
84. resolver = get_resolver(get_urlconf())
85. name = 'filebrowser'
86.
87. # Django's default name resolution method (see django.core.urlresolvers.reverse())
88. app_list = resolver.app_dict[app_name]
89. if not name in app_list:
90.   name = app_list[0]
91.    
92. return get_site_dict()[name]
```

I have forgot say that this error happens when I try run in console this:

```
manage.py loaddata ~/httpdocs/data-backup.json
```

This error not happens when DB is empty.

Comment: Could you provide the code from /home/vhosts/malinnikov.tomsk.ru/private/new_malinnikov/filebrowser/sites.py (or a small portion of it)? The exception is being thrown there, specifically at line 88.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the value for ROOT_URLCONF in your settings.py module? I haven't worked with the filebrowser app, but we can try to figure it out :)

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'new_malinnikov.urls'

Comment: It seems that the issue is that `_app_dict` isn't being populated with the `filebrowser` key. This function (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L257) is where this should be happening, and `apps` should be given that key. However I'm not sure what else is supposed to be going on before, because it looks like for that to happen the patterns in your urlconf need to be RegexURLResolver instances. I'll look around a bit more, but hopefully an expert will come answer your question soon :)

Comment: I got it. Just wrong version of filebrowser.

Comment: Haha awesome! I would not have gotten that. Udachi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Just wrong version of filebrowser.